# Nested Excel with additional command

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
=IF(AND(U4:U7="yes"),"YES","NO",OR(IF(ISBLANK(U4),"")))
```

I'm trying to get a column to

- return **yes** if all cells in the data set are yes and
- return **no** if one of the cells in the data set is no,
- but I am also wanting it to show blank if the cell is blank.

They would only be entered in sequence so that is why I chose U4.

Comment: " I am also wanting it to show blank if the cell is blank" which cell would that be? It would be useful to see sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nesting is a little off:

```
=IF(OR(U4:U7=""),"",IF(AND(U4:U7="yes"),"YES","NO"))
```